# How to load balance the Kafka Leadership?

Tags: apache-kafka

My kafka version is `kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1`. I have two brokers in the cluster, 4 topics and each topic has 4 partitions.

When I run

`sh kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper rhost:2181`

for all the topics/partitions, I see broker 1 as Leader.

How can I load balance the leader?

For example, for topic 1 and topic 2 have broker 1 as leader and
for topic 3 and topic 4 have broker 2 as leader.

Answer (score 19):

The partitions should be automatically rebalanced, since the default value of the broker configuration parameter `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` is `true`. (see [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs))

However, by default this rebalance occurs every 5 minutes, as defined by the `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds` parameter. If you wish this to occur more frequently, you will have to modify this parameter.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Preferred Replica Leader Election Tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-1.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionTool):

`sh kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper zklist`

This guarantees that the leadership load across the brokers in a cluster is evenly balanced.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late, maybe you already have the answer, but to balance leaders, first you need to make brokers equally preferred between all partitions, for a broker to be a "preferred leader" it has two criteria, first, it needs to be in sync replica, second, it has to be the first element on the replicas list. So, if you have a small enough number of topics/partitions, you can do that manually, it would be easier, otherwise you need to reassign partitions with distributing the first element (preferred replica) among all brokers, then kick off preferred leader election tool which will make sure that the preferred leader is actually the leader.

Answer (score 0):

Brokers have a property which can be set in `server.properties` file, which will enable auto re-balancing of the leadership. By default, it is not enabled. Add the following line of code to every broker and restart kafka.

`auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true`

Comment: ,I have enabled this "auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true" but it's not working.using 2 kafka with brokerId 0 and 1.if broker 0 stopped then broker 1 not act as a load balancing.Error I got is "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"

Comment: According to the current docs, the `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` value defaults to true, not false

Comment: Only v0.8 suggests setting it to true, 0.10 and above have that set to true by default. See Balancing leadership in v0.8 docs:
https://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html

Either way, when you describe a topic: leader "X" and first replica in the list (Y, Z, X) which has the preferred replica order should be same for all partitions for correct leader elections, some times this can be missing and sometimes, same node can be leader for many partitions - i.e., leaders in ISR can also be not balanced. 

You can always run the preferred replica election script to fix this problem.